# Stopping a macro if there's no value entered

Tags: excel, vba

I want my macro to stop if there's no value entered in any of the four cells I need. But i want it to run if there's at leats one value in those four cells.

This is what i have so far:

```
If Range("e12,h12,k12,d12").Value = "" Then
MsgBox ("Por favor introducir dimensiones")
Range("e12").Select
Exit Sub
End If
```

If you introduce a value in cell e12, it will run. But if you introduce a value in any other cell, the msgbox will pop out and the macro will stop.

Could you help me find the problem?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Please install the event procedure below in the code sheet of the worksheet on which you want the action.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Const Triggers As String = "E12,H12,K12,D12"
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim Cell As Range

    ' skip if more than one cell was changed (like paste)
    If Target.Cells.CountLarge = 1 Then
        Set Rng = Range(Triggers)
        For Each Cell In Rng
            If Cell.Value = "" Then
                Cell.Select
                Exit For
            End If
        Next Cell
    End If
End Sub
```

Now, if the user enters something in E12 the macro will select H12. If the user enters something in D12 next the macro will take him back to K12. That's all very nice.

But if the user changes something in A3 (anywhere, in fact) he will be taken to the first empty cell of the trigger range. Therefore the system must be tweaked to accommodate your workflow. Perhaps the code should be made to run only when D12 is entered, or when the user clicks on the cell he shouldn't click on before completing the trigger range.

In short, the scope of the procedure may have to be trimmed to suit your workflow. This can be done by either including specific cells in the trigger range, or by excluding other cells.

Comment: Well, this seems a bit too complicated for my beginner skills but i'll give it a try

Comment: Haha. You get only one chance to do anything for the first time. After that you are beginner at something else. Here it's just installing an event procedure in the correct location - and remember how it works.

Answer (score 0):

you coudl use `WorksheetFunction.CountA()` function to count the number of not empty cells:

```
If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("e12,h12,k12,d12")) <> 4 Then
    MsgBox ("Por favor introducir dimensiones")
    Range("e12").Select
    Exit Sub
End If
```

Comment: You are weclome. You may then want to mark answer as accepted to direct future readers, too...